# Rails 4: Persisting a raw quiz access token/password through browser-session (*NOT* user account password)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, session, cookies, authorization

I have a Rails 4 app that allows a user ("User") to create quizzes to be completed by respondents ("Respondent(s)"). The User has to sign-up and login to create quizzes. However, Respondents should not have to signup or login, BUT are required to submit the quiz name along with an authorization token ("Quiz Token") to access the intended quiz. I'm calling it a "token" here to avoid confusion with the User's password, but essentially the Quiz Token is a password to access a specified Quiz. The idea is that the User is responsible for distributing the token to the Respondents by whatever means including visually through the app (e.g., clicking a button to display it on a projector/screen).

I am currently implementing the Quiz Token in the Quiz model like so:

```
  # Returns a random token.
  def Quiz.new_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(6)
  end

  # Generates new token and assigns to quiz, then saves digest to DB.
  def remember
    self.quiz_token = Quiz.new_token
    update_attribute(:quiz_digest, Quiz.digest(quiz_token))
  end

  # comparison of raw token to stored digest
  def authenticated?(quiz_token)
    quiz_digest.nil? ? false :
    BCrypt::Password.new(quiz_digest).is_password?(quiz_token)
  end
```

**My question lies in how to go about persisting the raw Quiz Token ("quiz_token" in code sample), of which there may be several of these associated with active Quiz instances, so that it is retained at least throughout the browser-session within which it was generated?**

My initial implementation is limited to a flash notice displaying the new Quiz Token to the User following 'create' or 'reset' actions in the controller. The problem with this is that it only occurs once and I want to allow the User to retain the ability to display the Quiz Token later in the browser-session. I've thought about storing the Quiz Token in the session hash, but I'm worried this will get messy as there may be several active Quiz instances and therefore several Quiz Tokens requiring (?) deeply nested hashes resembling something like `session[:quiz_id][:quiz_token]`. Are cookies a more appropriate approach? Finally, from what I gather, it is never okay to store raw anything-of-this-nature in the DB ... right? (I'm unclear what is best-practice in this situation as it's a shared password/token, so, I would think, assumed to be inherently compromised by nature.)

Thanks for any ideas/advice here.

Comment: why don't you use [surveyor](https://github.com/NUBIC/surveyor) it should make your life much easier.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, however, this is mostly a learning app for me, so I'm trying to minimize the gem bundle installs especially where they'd preclude me from learning large chunks of useful stuff. I know there are plenty of apps that do the same as this and gems that make the road easier, but this is (part of) my self-directed "bootcamp", if you will. also, my question is more directed in programmatic approach than specific syntax for making it work. thanks again for the comment though. I do appreciate it! Cheers. @pshoukry

Comment: You are welcome, well if that's what you want will take a deeper look and try to suggest a solution to your specific problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I ended up sticking in my controller actions ('create' and 'reset'):

```
if @foo.save
 session[:quiz_tokens] ||= {}
 session[:quiz_tokens][@foo.id] = @foo.quiz_token
.
.
.
end
```

Then just call it from the view, something like:

```
<% if session[:quiz_tokens].has_key?(@foo.id) %>

  <h2><%= session[:quiz_tokens][@foo.id] %></h2>
.
.
.
<% end %>
```